# Find smallest positive integer $n$ such that $n!$ is divisible by $p^k$ ($p =$ positive prime, $k =$ positive integer)

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial, prime-factorization

I have to find smallest positive integer $n$ in such way that $n!$ is divisible by $p^k$ ($p$ is always positive prime and $k$ is always positive integer).

**$p$ and $k$ are given, $n$ is (obviously not known)**

I know about [Legendre's (de Polignac's) formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) but it is not the same?

Do you have any ideas how to do this ? I tried rearranging Legendres formula but it is not necessary  true that biggest power of $p$ that divides $n$ is the same to $p^k$ that divides the smallest $n!$ ? Or is it the same?

*For example, if $p = 2$ and $k = 5$, the result is $n = 8$, since $8!$ is
the smallest factorial divisible by $2^5$.*

Thank you.

**EDIT: I don't know if this is thinking in right or wrong direction but: simplifying Legendres formula to $ n = k * (p - 1) $ always comes pretty close:**

*Example: $p = 31$ $k = 750$ solution $n = 22537$ ; With above formula i get $n = 22500$*

Should I be rather modyfing this formula to get it or is it completely different ?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. First thoughts (not even enough for a hint). Clearly $n$ will be a multiple of $p$. Figure out the answer using brute force for $p=2$ and perhaps $p=3$ for the first few values of $k$ and see if a pattern or computational method emerges.

Comment: Thank you, yes I have tried that, I have also tried simplifying Legendres formula (instead of sum of infinte series using: $k = n/(p-1)$, but I cannot seem to get anything useful out of it. Don't know might be something simple I am missing...

Comment: Maybe set $n = p^\ell$ where $\ell$ is the smallest integer so that $\sum_{i=1}^\ell i \geq k$? A

Comment: nevermind, that will probably be too large.

Answer (score 2):

A variant of Legendre's formula is that $v_p(n!) = \frac{n - S_p(n)}{p-1}$.
So we are seeking for the smallest $n$ such that
$$ n - S_p(n) \ge (p-1)k. $$
Thus clearly $n > (p-1) k$. As $S_p(n) \le p \log_p n$, if $n - p \log_p n \ge (p-1)k$ then $p^k \mid n!$. As $\log n$ is small compared to $n$, I think $(p-1)k$ is close enough to the right answer, whose exact value I don't think one can find good ''formula'' with.